# How we describe scientifically easy and difficult dataset?

Tags: classification, regression, dataset

Sometimes we hear that a dataset is easy or difficult for a same task (like classifying cats and dogs). How we can describe it in scientific way( math or probability or statistics). For example we reach to accuracy of 99% for first dataset but for another one we reach at top 80% for accuracy.

Comment: usually we say that a dataset is as difficult as the gap between the state of the art model accuracy and the human accuracy

Comment: btw, seems that there is a correlation between the entropy encoded in the dataset and the difficulty https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.08420.pdf

Comment: It's often possible to be more precise, for instance by saying that the dataset contains a lot of noise or that it it's too small or not a good representative sample.

Comment: Thanks. That is a good article